# Angle between two gradient

Tags: geometry

**The equation of a curve is xy = 12 and the equation of a line l is 2x + y = k, where k is a constant.**

**In the case where k = 10, one of the points of intersection is P (2, 6). Find the angle, in degrees correct to 1 decimal place, between l and the tangent to the curve at P. [4]**

Gradient of L=-2 
Gradient of tangent to curve=-3

How to find the angle between the 2 gradients, without a specific(direct) equation.

Comment: $$\tan\theta=\pm\frac{-2-(-3)}{1+(-2)(-3)}=\pm\frac17$$

Comment: How do you derive to this formula ??

Comment: @Arodioo7, http://easycalculation.com/analytical/learn-angle-between-two-curves.php

Comment: The site doesn't explain how to get the formula but only replace values in it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient of both curves are $\tan\theta_1,\tan\theta_2$ of the angles with the positive x-axis and so the required and $\theta=\theta_1-\theta_2$ and so
$$\tan\theta=\tan(\theta_1-\theta_2)=\frac{\tan\theta_1-\tan\theta_2}{1+\tan\theta_1*\tan\theta_2}$$
As lab wrote it may differ by a sign.

Comment: How tanθ1=gradient ??

Comment: this is by the definition of the derivative

Comment: I mean how to get tan, the hypotenuse is always equal to -2 or -3....

Comment: Read this(http://www.vitutor.com/calculus/derivatives/geometric_interpretation.html)